# Selenium Webdriver findElement promise does not resolve

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with NodeJS and Chromedriver. I'm running a basic test: open a webpage and find 3 elements. The strangest thing happen with an image element. (I must click it but it always throws and error). When I run the following code:

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('img.arrow-icon')), 5000);
driver.findElement(By.css('img.arrow-icon')).then(function(el){
    console.log("!!!!!!!!!!! " + el.getTagName());
})
```

I get the following result:

```
!!!!!!!!!!! ManagedPromise::221 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}
```

Is it possible to have an unresolved promise inside .then()?!?!?

My initial code was this:

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('img.arrow-icon')), 5000).click();
```

That always throws this error:

```
ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

I must say that there are other 2 elements in the page that webdriver finds without problem. Somehow, it has an issue with this image.. I don't know.. Please help!

**EDIT:** 
I have tried using

```
driver.sleep(5000);
```

..still, no success. I receive the error with "element not visible", but the image is there; I can see it right from the start

Comment: Are you sure your locator is correct? Are you sure your locator isn't finding more than one element on the page and the first one is invisible and not the one you want?

Comment: Also, if you plan to click the element once you find it, don't wait for element located, wait for element to be clickable. That way, once it's found you can immediately click it. Element located just means it's in the DOM, not that it's visible or clickable. Make sure your waits match up with your actions (when possible). It will make your tests more reliable.

Comment: thanks for the tips JeffC, I'm verifying what you said

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get over this issue by finding the element By.xpath (I have to mention though, that the CSS selector was fine; it worked using jQuery) I have no idea why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you return the driver.findElement() function. You need to do this so it will be used for the el variable. Try this and it should work.

```html
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('img.arrow-icon')), 5000);
return driver.findElement(By.css('img.arrow-icon')).then(function(el){
    console.log("!!!!!!!!!!! " + el.getTagName());
})
```

Remember that you have to return a value to use within the .then function.